# Thread safe file access

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a program that does a large number of comparisons. It compares a specific .dat file saved on the local machine to a large number of other files that are generated on run-time. Right now I am unable to perform these comparisons using multiple threads because of many `System.AccessViolationException`. I'm assuming this is because multiple threads are trying to access the same local file at the same time. How can I overcome this to do these comparisons with multiple threads?

Comment: How large are the *.dat files? Are you reading the file in such a way that it prevents other threads/processes from accessing it (e.g. the `FileStream.Open()` method takes a parameter that allows you to specify which mode the file is opened in and how it can be shared).

Comment: can you be more specific in regards to what it is you are comparing. also what is the significance in regards to what you are trying to compare on the local vs the other large files.. perhaps you are taking the wrong approach.. This is a very hard question to answer based on the little bit of information you have provided

Comment: Show the code you use to open the files and the lines that give the access violations.

Comment: Does anyone need to write the .dat file? If not, any number of readers can share it with no problems.

Comment: Sorry updating right now with more detail

Comment: `AccessViolationException` is caused by unmanaged code, not managed code.

Comment: I believe accessing file in multiple threads won't throw `AccessViolationException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possible reasons for your access violation:

1. Multiple threads are exclusively locking your specific .dat file
2. Your multi-threading is buggy in the regard that multiple threads try to read the same runtime generated file
3. Your multi-threading is buggy in the regard that your threads try to read the runtime generated files before they have been generated completely

The following solutions exist:

1. Read the .dat file into memory once and share that data between all threads. This also reduces the I/O load
2. Make sure every runtime generated file is compared only by one thread. This can be achieved by a thread safe queue that contains all files that need to be compared and that is shared between all threads.
3. Make sure that the runtime generated file gets known to the reading threads only after it has been created completely. This can be achieved by creating it in a different directory on the same disk and moving it to the target directory putting the file name into the queue from solution 2 only after creation is completed.

---

As Matthew Watson correctly points out, an `AccessViolationException` is caused by errors in unmanaged code, so it is probably not caused by multiple threads trying to access the same file.
My answer therefore assumes that you are actually getting an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.
If that is not the case and you are indeed getting an `AccessViolationException` your problem most likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: I'm dubious that `AccessViolationException` can be caused by managed code. I suspect there's something else going on here involving unmanaged code and P/Invoke that the OP hasn't told us.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: You are correct. I amended my answer with a "disclaimer".

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for not giving enough information. I'm using an external sdk that reads the .dat file into a Buffer(part of the sdk) and then processes it from there. I'll give your recommendations a try.